# Reply comment via email in PHP

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have developed a website using PHP and MYSQL. The website has a commenting system through which all users of the website can post comments on the feedback posted by different users.

When a comment is posted for a feedback an email is sent to the user who posted that feedback notifying him of new comments on his feedback.

Now what I want is that a feedback owner should be able to post a new comment in response to that comment by simply replying to the email that has been sent by the website.

I hope I was able to explain my query properly. If it needs any improvement in explanation, I would be glad to know and make changes accordingly

Thanks

Comment: Well, what are you having trouble with? Basically you will need some cron to keep logging into an email account, which gets all the replies, and read the new emails, and propagate properly into the database. Start by looking into how to log in to POP3/IMAP accounts and have one ready for receiving the emails

Comment: This looks much more like a requirement than a question. You need to explain what problem your are facing and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an own e-mail account for the comment system and set this e-mail as "From" when the e-mail is sent.

The subject should contain something like [Comment#123] to identify the one comment.

Now when someone replys on the E-Mail it receives in the mailbox of the comment system.

The next step is to check the mailbox via IMAP:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Read all E-Mails from the account, parse the subject and search for the comment id.
Get the E-Mail body, insert it in your database and delete the commend.

This will give the best performance when run in a cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a token, save the token in your DB in association with your user, add it to your email, then when your server will receive emails it will be able to know who send the email (I mean user and feedback) and store the comment in your DB. And be very careful to the sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use php as a mail client. You have to connect using php to the pop3/imap server who store the emails sent to you ( the replies of the users ). Than check the new emails, read the information in the tile to gain wath reply it is and than save the data in the database. But it can be done "live" just using php. You need a chron-job who check the email or a daemon installed on your server. Otherwise the data will be updated only when someone log on the php script
Sorry for my bad english